# Can I publish WP7.x on MS App store

Tags: windows-phone-7

It is not so clear on the MS site if they let me do that. I know there are quite a few of WP7.x devices and the 7.x apps are supposed to run on wp8.x phones I want to cover the lower devices, will they let me publish it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. If you publish only one package and this supports WP7, the app will run on all WP devices. Alternatively, you might publish two packages for the same app, one that targets WP7 and one for WP8 or WP8.1, then the store decides which package to download depending on the device - this allows you to make use of new WP8.x features while still providing a simpler app for WP7 users!